# Update 10.04 to 12.04

Tags: update-alternatives

In home PC Ubuntu 10.04 installed and no internet connection. I want to update it to 12.04.

i want download from my office PC (it is connected with internet)

Can I download only updated portion not entire OS.

Comment: Is the 10.04 version you have LTS?

Answer (score 0):

If you can wait until February 6th then Ubuntu 12.04.4 will be released which contains all of the latest 12.04 updates as well...  That way you will have an up-to-date fresh install when you take your freshly burnt CD or Flash Drive home to play with...